# How to create the custom loss function by adding negative entropy to the cross-entropy?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I recently read a paper entitled "REGULARIZING NEURAL NETWORKS BY PENALIZING CONFIDENT OUTPUT DISTRIBUTIONS [https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.06548"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.06548%22). The authors discuss regularizing neural networks by penalizing low entropy
output distributions through adding a negative entropy term to the negative log-likelihood and creating a custom loss function for model training.

[image]

The value β controls the strength of confidence penalty. I have written a custom function for categorical cross-entropy as shown below but the negative entropy term need to be added to the loss function.

```
import tensorflow as tf
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    cce = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()
    cce_loss = cce(y_true, y_pred)    
    return cce_loss
```

Comment: It could be better if you add the link of the paper. Anyway, what is the `H` function?

Comment: H is the entropy function; the link to the paper is added,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entropy of `y_pred` is essentially the categorical cross entropy between `y_pred` and itself:

[image]

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred, beta):
    cce = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()
    return cce(y_true, y_pred) - beta*cce(y_pred, y_pred)
```

Comment: Thanks. I am also accepting your answer since the relationship holds.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a custom loss, as it can be implemented as an activity regularizer (one applied to the output of a layer):

```
def regularizer(beta):
    def entropy_reg(inp):
        return -beta * K.mean(inp * K.log(inp))
```

Then this can be applied to your output layer:

```
model = Sequential()
#Add layers here
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax",
          activity_regularizer=regularizer(0.01)))
```